# Changing column name dynamically in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe with 50 columns. The problem with index row is that, all of them columns are named to: ***Unnamed.***

I want to rename the columns. I know that with dataframes you rename the columnsthis way:

```
df.rename(columns={"A": "a", "B": "c"})
```

But as I have 50 columns, I want to rename the columns through a loop for learning and efficiencie sake.

I want to rename **column 0** to `'Name'`, **column 1** to `Country` and the rest to `Group 1, Group 2` and so on.

Here is my solution so far for column 3 to 50. I was thinking of renaming the first 2 columns manually as I cannot come with a better way to do within the loop.

```
for col in df.columns[2:]:
    start = 'Group'
    x = 1
    name = '{}'+x.format(start)
    df = df.rename(columns={col:name})
    x = x+1
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Now I understand that, this is because of the x value. But I'cant come up with a way for the column name to change dynamically for every column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define x before the loop in order it not to start from 1 again and again. Instead of start variable you can use string 'Group '. Variable x shoud be transfered to string format. This will give you the possibility to concatenate two strings - 'Group ' and respective x number.

```
x = 1
for col in df.columns[2:]:
  name = 'Group '+str(x)
  df = df.rename(columns={col:name})
  x = x+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that `x` is an `int` and you want to get a string `'Group <x>'`, you just use

```
    name = 'Group {:d}'.format(x)
```

or

```
    name = '{} {:d}'.format(start, x)
```

if you like. If you prefer to use `+` for concatenation instead of format strings, you could use

```
    name = start + ' ' + str(x)
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the response. I tried with your suggestions but all of the columns are still named to: Zone 1. It doesn't seem to add +1 to the x?